# I am not able to get the IMEI from My Device My API Level is 24 and OS is Nougat

Tags: java, android, imei

I am trying to find my IMEI no but unable to get from my device here is code.I have provided my perssion in my android manifest but still I cannot find. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Context context;
TextView imei_number;
Button get_imei;
String IMEI_Number_Holder;
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;



   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        imei_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        get_imei = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 0);
        } else {
            //TODO
        }
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        get_imei.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},1);
                    IMEI_Number_Holder = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }


                imei_number.setText(IMEI_Number_Holder);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I have tried many ways but Cannot able to get Please help me. Here is another code which I have tried this code but getting error like

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10183 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

What should I do Please guide me I am tried many ways in google but not much help.My device is OS is Nougat

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        String imeiNumber1 = tm.getDeviceId(1); //(API level 23)
        String imeiNumber2 = tm.getDeviceId(2);

    }

    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
```

Comment: When you request a permission you don't already have you need to wait until you get the `RequestPermissionResult` before calling the function that needs the permission (i.e. `getDeviceId` in this case).

Comment: No than what should i do

Comment: The code (before the latest edit) contained comments suggesting what you should do to handle the permission requests properly, so I find it curious that you didn't attempt to do what the comments suggested.

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: Can you please post your complete activity code here? Because its unclear from where are you calling the second code block.

Comment: Posted my code check

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your `onClick` method:

```
get_imei.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, READ_PHONE_STATE_REQUEST);

        } else {

            IMEI_Number_Holder = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            imei_number.setText(IMEI_Number_Holder);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem was in the order of your actions. You are checked if `permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`, which mean **not granted** and right after that invoked `getDeviceId()`.